# What if a reference is declared to point to itself? E.g. int& x = x;

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

The following code compiles successfully in `g++` version 10.1.0:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int& x = x;
    return x;
}
```

The compiler even has a warning defined for this, suggesting it's intentional that it isn't an error. When compiled with `-Wall`, it returns the following output:

```
<stdin>: In function ‘int main()’:
<stdin>:3:14: warning: reference ‘x’ is initialized with itself [-Winit-self]
    3 |         int& x = x;
      |              ^
<stdin>:3:14: warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    3 |         int& x = x;
      |
```

My testing has shown that this results in a reference to a value at address 0, same as if it were declared as the `int& x = *(int*)nullptr;`. Naturally, this results in a segfault if the value referenced by `x` is ever used.

I can think of one (questionable) case where this might be useful: if you want to call a method on a class with no accessible constructor, when that method isn't `static` but nonetheless doesn't make any use of the class's data:

```cpp
struct S {
    S() = delete;
    int value() { return 69; }
};

int main()
{
    S& s = s;
    return s.value();
}
```

But then there are other ways to do that, which don't even give warnings with `-Wall` and are less likely to be undefined behavior. (For example, `((S*)0)->value()`.)

So what I'm asking is: *is* this in fact undefined behavior? It certainly seems like something that would be. Is there any conceivable situation in which a self-reference is the best solution? And if not, why is the warning suppressed by default?

Comment: `((S*)0)->value()` is definitely undefined behavior.

Comment: Compilers do not have to warn for all cases of undefined behavior (UB).  Some UB requires a diagnostic, but a lot of UB explicitly has *no diagnostic required* (NDR) in the C++ standard, and other UB is left unsaid.  Some compilers provided warnings for some of the NDR and unsaid cases, and some require opt-in.  Bottom line:  C++ is not a nanny language, and will give you plenty of rope to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this code is accepted is because the C++ grammar allows for it; not because there is any practical reason for it.

In the C++ grammar, the first part of the definition introduces the name identifier which may be in in the rest of the scope, including in the same statement. This is what allows you to have code like:

```cpp
int x = 1, &y = x;
```

The first `int x` produces the name `x` which may be used anywhere after it is seen. This has the side-effect of also allowing self-assignment, such as:

```cpp
int x = x;
```

This assignment is, in fact, undefined behavior because `x` is not yet a initialized object, and is thus reading from uninitialized data (which is UB).

The same is true with a self-assigned reference; the `int& x` introduces the name `x`, whereas `= x` binds to a type that is bindable to a reference (which also happens to be `int& x`). This reference was not yet initialized by the time it was assigned, so this access is undefined behavior.

The compiler is free to treat undefined behavior however it chooses -- which it appears you are observing gcc treating the referenced address as `0x0`. This is not guaranteed behavior, and may be influenced based on compiler version, optimization level, etc.

---

There is no real practical purpose for this; but it is easy to combat with using modern practices like `auto`, since code using `auto` in a self-construction will be unable to deduce the underlying type:

```cpp
auto x = x;  // error, cannot deduce x
auto& y = y; // error, cannot deduce y
```

> why is the warning suppressed by default?

The C++ standard only indicates a handful of errors that require diagnostic messages. Many errors fall under "no diagnostic required", which compilers may choose to add warnings for through optional flags. This is up to the implementation's discretion, and would be a question for the compiler's authors.

Most uninitialized access errors don't require diagnostics, which I am assuming this falls under.

---

As for your questionable-reason for using a self-reference: this would be undefined behavior, as is your example `((S*)0)->value()`.

Since the reference is constructed from UB, accessing any members from it is also UB.

For your other example, any form of member access on a null pointer is undefined behavior regardless of whether that member function accesses any member state, or whether it gets inlined. This doesn't mean it may not *work* with the right compiler flags on the right compiler; but it is *not* a portable, reliable, or safe solution.

Comment: _which it appears GCC chooses to bind to address 0x0_ I think that's just happenstance, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9eRnmy5LIbc8xL9U

Comment: Interesting observation! I'll update my answer. The main thing I was getting at is that this is undefined behavior, so the compiler can do whatever it really chooses in this scenario

Comment: Thanks for your answer—very well explained!

Comment: @PaulSanders: Interesting - if I change the line to `std::cout << &y << ", " << &x;` then `&x` is once again zero.

Comment: @flarn2006: With Undefined Behavior, `&x` can be null and non-null at the same time. `&x` can also be purple, as far as the C++ Standard is concerned. There are simply no guarantees anymore. Don't try to draw too much conclusions from such tests.

Comment: @MSalters: So you're saying I've created a quantum computer? ;) Anyway, to be serious, I'm aware that it doesn't mean anything aside from some technical trivia about that specific compiler. I was just pointing it out as I found it interesting that for whatever reason it behaved that way.